# GestureDetector execute script with child

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to execute a code on **GestureDetector** in this case with `onLongPressDetected` and also to change the content of the page, but I'm stuck at trying to make **GestureDetector** do both.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return GestureDetector(
      onLongPress: onLongPressDetected,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text('Test')
            ]
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
}
```

I tried adding the function instead of `onLongPressDetected` but then I get the script to execute but the page remains the same(so the child is ignored).
Can you please help me? Is there any way I can add some dart code to be executed with the **GestureDetector**?

Edit, solution I found:

```dart
void Function()? test() {
  print("Test");
  return onLongPressDetected;
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return GestureDetector(
      onLongPress: test(),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text('Test')
            ]
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
}
```

Comment: If you are making any changes in any data that is displayed in the UI, you need to update the state using setState or whatever state management you are using. Only then the changes will be reflected in the UI.

Comment: Thanks to the moderator for editing and thanks to you both, I figured out how to accomplish what I needed, I edited the post..

Comment: I need to execute a function instead of only onLongPressDetected, but I figured it out already. Thanks anyway.